# echo a date 0 if the amount becomes minus

Tags: php, function, datetime, date-difference

I have the following function

```
function get_designment_info_by_id($id) {
    $this->db->where('designment_id', $id);
    $designment_info = $this->db->get('designments')->row_array();
    $designment_info['image'] = self::get_image_for_designment($id);
    $designment_info['count_joined'] = self::get_users_count_joined_by_id($id);
    $designment_info['count_ideas'] = self::get_users_count_ideas_by_id($id);
    $date_to = $designment_info['date_to'];
        $diff = $date_to - now();
        $days = round($diff / 86400);
        $time_left = $days . ' days';



        $designment_info['time_left'] = $time_left;
    return $designment_info;
}
```

Now in the view if the date has passed it will show how much days the date has passed. for example if the deadline was 02-06-16 it will show '-4 days' how can I change the function it will echo just a zero '0' if the deadline has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's negative before assignment, then zero it out if so.

```
$days = round($diff / 86400);
if ($days < 0) $days = 0;
$time_left = $days . ' days';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a if condition

```
function get_designment_info_by_id($id) {
    $this->db->where('designment_id', $id);
    $designment_info = $this->db->get('designments')->row_array();
    $designment_info['image'] = self::get_image_for_designment($id);
    $designment_info['count_joined'] = self::get_users_count_joined_by_id($id);
    $designment_info['count_ideas'] = self::get_users_count_ideas_by_id($id);
    $date_to = $designment_info['date_to'];
    $diff = $date_to - now();
    $days = round($diff / 86400);
    // Add this
    if($days < 0){
        $days = 0;
    }
    $time_left = $days . ' days';



    $designment_info['time_left'] = $time_left;
    return $designment_info;
}
```

Comment: `$time_left` is a string

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I found that. edited my answer. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever datetime is being manipulated using the *magic number* `86400`, there is generally a risk of unwanted DST interference.  To totally avoid this, I have written a process using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) without leveraging `86400`.

```
// assumes $designment_info['date_to'] is formatted d-m-y from question
$date_to=DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y',$designment_info['date_to']);
$date_now=new DateTime("now");
if($date_to<=$date_now){
    echo "0 days"; // not yet passed
}else{
    $passed=$date_to->diff($date_now)->days;
    echo "$passed day",($passed>1?"s":"");  // add plural when needed
}
```

Here is an [online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5946dbdbe381650ba118e9775ef854e8a652999) that shows `$date_to` as before, equal to, and after `$date_now`. (...for today anyhow)

Comment: @sterrek If my answer satisfies your question, please award it the green tick so your question is removed from the unanswered questions list.  (if you find it helpful, you are welcome to upvote it as well ;))